# Keras producing error while working with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, imagedatagenerator

I am trying to do simple task in which the model takes an image as input and produce another image as output. There are two folders named *input* which contains the input images and another folder named *output* which contains the ground truth images or y label.
To split the entire folder in training and validation split I did following steps:

```
# This is supposed to make training split which contains x label
train_set_X = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    class_mode='input',
    classes=['input'],
    subset='training'
)

# This is supposed to make validation split which contains x label
validation_set_X = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    class_mode='input',
    classes=['input'],
    subset ='validation'
)


# THis makes the training split's Y label

train_set_Y = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_cleaned_path,
    class_mode='input',
    classes=['output'],
    subset ='training'
)

# THis makes the validation split's Y label
validation_set_Y =train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_cleaned_path,
    class_mode='output',
    classes=['train_cleaned'],
    subset ='validation'
)
```

but when I used above mentioned splits as follows :

```
history= conv_NN.fit(train_set_X, train_set_Y,
                              validation_data = (validation_set_X, validation_set_Y), 
                              epochs=20, batch_size=16,
                              callbacks= [early_stop,tensorboard_callback], 
                              verbose=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input.
```

Kindly help me to know what is going on here and what wrong I am doing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

when using generators model.fit expects the generator to provide both the x and y values. Therefore you can not specify the y labels as you did with the code

```
history= conv_NN.fit(train_set_X, train_set_Y
```

I think you can achieve what you want with

```
train_gen=zip(train_set_X,train_set_Y)
valid_gen=zip(validation_set_X,validation_set_Y)
history= conv_NN.fit(train_gen,valisation_data = valid_gen,  
                              epochs=20, batch_size=16,
                              callbacks= [early_stop,tensorboard_callback], 
                              verbose=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. I zipped the dataset as you said but I got another error as :  ValueError: Layer "sequential_1" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>]

Comment: My model is initialized as Sequential() and first layer is Conv2.

Comment: try running image, label=next(train_gen) the print(image,shape, label.shape) to help see if the generator is producing the right outputs

Comment: OK found the problem. In your generators set class_mode=None and classes=None. That way the generator produces only the image and not a label, When class_mode='input the generator produces both the image and a label